# Unlocking an Android phone

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, password, pattern-lock

I forgot the password to my Android phone (I have a Samsung A51) and I am trying to reset the lock password. It is important for me not to reset because I have important information that I want to obtain. I understand computers and Linux and less so on Android. The password is a drawing pattern and not a PIN and I tried through ADB it gave me problems because I don't have the USB Debugging mode so it's bugging me, I would appreciate your help I have essential information there

I tried to search for information on the internet and I also tried through software like dr.fone and it doesn't work because the model is not supported

Comment: The Android lock screen is designed to allow access to the device only to people who know the lockscreen pattern/pin/password. A possibility to bypass this would be a sever vulnerability as it would render the pattern/pin/password useless.

Comment: Android 8.0 had this vulnerability but they fixed it in 8.1... So no hopes. If only you could plug it to pc and enable file transfer, that's all you can do. Even "Find My Device" doesn't offer to reset the password anymore (right? Correct me if I'm wrong)